# Is applyTwice a well-known Haskell idiom?

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

Is this a well-known idiom?

```
applyTwice :: (a -> b -> c) -> (d -> a) -> (d -> b) -> (d -> c)
applyTwice g f1 f2 p = g (f1 p) (f2 p)
```

Here's a typical use:

```
applyTwice someFunction head tail $ this $ that $ otherThing
```

In this case, `this $ that $ otherThing` returns a list, and I want to take *both* the head and tail of that list, and then supply the two ends to `someFunction`.

Is `applyTwice` a standard idiom, or is there some more natural way to take both the head and tail of the result of a complex calculation? Is just using `where` the standard way to do this?

Comment: Definitely belongs on StackOverflow. If this was about the theory behind Haskell it might be on topic, but asking about idioms and usage is definitely for SO.

Comment: `applyTwice g f1 f2 = (g.f1) <*> f2`. So, yes, and no; it's an [**S** combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus) from combinatory logic and lambda-calculus.

Comment: a related Haskell combinator is Data.Function.on: ``(g `on` f) x y = g (f x) (f y)`` but that goes the other way around, with "one function, two arguments".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't it just `liftM2`?          .

Comment: Perfect!  Hoogle didn't find the signature because my "d" wasn't any specific type.  But I was being too general -- I should have realized that my use of "d" was against an array, and liftM2 acts upon arrays-as-monads.

Comment: @MarshallhandheldFlax Actually, here `liftM` is using the function `Monad` instance, `(->) r`. It's unrelated to your use of arrays and will work on the fully general type you gave.

Comment: Also, one thing that's kind of useful about GHCi is you can use it to see if something can take on a certain type, which is nice if you have some type class complexity going on. `:t liftM2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> (d -> a) -> (d -> b) -> (d -> c)` shows that `liftM2` can have this type.